# Using formula to update another cell?

Tags: excel

I would like that cell B1 is incremented if A1 has a value of 1 
else C1 should be incremented

```
 |1                  |2|3|4|
A|=if(A1=1;B1+1;C1+1)| | | |
B|                   | | | |
C|                   | | | |
```

and I would like to increment other cells if A1 = 1

Comment: For that you'll need VBA code or maybe with recursive calculation, but that might become an issue to use recursive in your case...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since a formula can only directly modify the contents of the cell that contains it, this isn't possible using spreadsheet formulas, even with circular references enabled. There is a VBA solution which (roughly) does what you want. Add the following code to the worksheet's code module:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$A$1" Then
        If Target.Value = 1 Then
            Range("B1").Value = Range("B1").Value + 1
        Else
            Range("C1").Value = Range("C1").Value + 1
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

When `A1` changes in value, if the change is to 1 then `B1` increments, otherwise `C1` increments.

Answer (score 1):

For this you have to write the formula in B1 and C1 cell but you can not increment it's own value in the formula because it will give circular reference error , so you have to store the original values of B1 and C1 in some other column (you can hide them) and increase the value of those columns in the formula. (but it will increase the values only first time when the value will become 1 in A1).